# Como migrar código de C a python

Tags: python, c++, c

Tengo esté código en c y me gustaría migrarlo a python3, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Especialmente la estructura E que no la entiendo muy bien

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct E{
    int ind,W,S;

    E(){
    }

    E(int _ind, int _W, int _S){
      ind=_ind;
      W=_W;
      S=_S;
    }

    bool operator < (E X) const{
      if(W!=X.W) return W<X.W;
      return S>X.S;
      }
   };

int main(){
    int n=0,W,S;
    E a[1000];

while(scanf("%d %d",&W,&S)==2) a[n]=E(++n,W,S);
sort(a,a+n);

int dp[n],next[n],ans=0,start;

for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
    dp[i]=1;
    next[i]=-1;

    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
        if(a[i].W<a[j].W && a[i].S>a[j].S && 1+dp[j]>dp[i]){
            dp[i]=1+dp[j];
            next[i]=j;
        }
    }

    if(dp[i]>ans){
        ans=dp[i];
        start=i;
    }
}

printf("%d\n",ans);
for(int i=start;i!=-1;i=next[i]) printf("%d\n",a[i].ind);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola! Lo que podrías hacer para pasar la estructura a python es con clases, crear una clase que se parezca a esa estructura y listo(?

Comment: ¿ese código compila?

Comment: Así tal cual está, el código no compila y tampoco se sabe qué es lo que hace. Por otro lado, a juzgar por las primeras líneas, se parece más a C++ que C. Al menos deberías poner un código que ejecute bien, para luego poder traducirlo.

Comment: Parece que, aunque el código que muestras es incorrecto, la idea es tener una clase que meramente almacena datos, y define un comparador para poder luego ordenar objetos de ese tipo. En python tendrías que definir `__lt__()` en vez de `<`. Por otro lado, Python 3.7 (la última versión) trae las llamadas [datclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) para este tipo de necesidades.

Comment: Ya arreglé el codigo, pero alguien sabe especificamente como migrar el apartedo de sobrecarga de operadores? nisiquiera entiendo muy bien como sirve y es por eso que se me dificulta pasarlo a python, es esta parte:
        bool operator < (E X) const{
        if(W!=X.W) return W<X.W;
        return S>X.S;
       }
   };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que preguntas específicamente por la sobrecarga del operador `<`, te respondo que en python los operadores no se pueden sobrecargar, pero que las clases tienen unos métodos con nombres especiales (doble guión bajo al principio y al final) que son usados de forma especial por el intérprete python.

Así, cuando en tu código aparece la expresión `a < b`, Python mirará si `a` tiene definido el método `__lt__()` y de ser así lo invocará pasándole `b` como parámetro. Si no, entonces mirará si `b` tiene el método `__gt__()` y lo invocará pasándole `a` como parámetro. Si tampoco existe ese método, usará su implementación por defecto de cómo comparar `a` con `b`, y esa implementación depende de los tipos en concreto de esos datos (para números, cadenas y listas está definido, para objetos no).

Así pues definiendo una clase `E` e implementando en ella el método `__lt__()` puedes decidir cómo se comparan dos objetos de la clase `E` (o ya puestos cómo comparar un objeto de la clase `E` con cualquier otro tipo de datos, si crees que eso puede tener sentido).

Ejemplo:

```
class E:
  def __init__(self, ind, W, S):
    self.ind = ind
    self.W = W
    self.S = S

  def __lt__(self, otro):
    if isinstance(otro, E):
      if self.W != otro.W:
        return self.W < otro.W
      else:
        return self.S > otro.S
    else:
      raise TypeError("'<' not supported between instances of '{}' and '{}'"
              .format(type(self).__name__, type(otro).__name__))
```

La implementación de `__lt__()` es un poco más compleja de lo que debería, porque he querido comprobar que el otro objeto con que se está comparando sea también del tipo `E`, generando una excepción si no lo es (imitando así el comportamiento de python cuando intentas comparar cosas que no se pueden comparar).

Ejemplos de salida:

```
>>> E(0,1,1) < E(0,2,2)
True
>>> E(0,2,2) < E(0,1,1)
False
>>> E(0,1,2) < E(0,1, 3)
False
>>> E(0,1,2) < "Foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "python", line 14, in __lt__
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'E' and 'str'
```